# tab press is not working properly

Tags: focus, tabindex

here my code-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVndPassword" MaxLength="10" TabIndex="6" ToolTip="Password" Style="border: 1px solid #ededed;"
CssClass="inputDelivery paddBottom5px" TextMode="Password" runat="server" onkeyup="javascript:checkPasswordStrength(this.value);"></asp:TextBox>
```

when I am typing any word it is firing javascript method on each press but then I press `tab` button it is not focusing to next control but it focus to the same control and fire java script function too. But if I again press tab button now it focus to next control and even javascript is not fired this time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code for checkPasswordStrength? You need to ensure that the tab key is not caught in that method and that it returns true.  You also might try changing the onkeyup call to look like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVndPassword" MaxLength="10" TabIndex="6" ToolTip="Password" Style="border: 1px solid #ededed;" CssClass="inputDelivery paddBottom5px" TextMode="Password" runat="server" onkeyup="javascript:checkPasswordStrength(this.value); return true;"></asp:TextBox>
```